# Error Could not find com.google.gms.google-services:4.3.15

Tags: flutter, gradle

> How do I solve the error?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
  Could not find com.google.gms.google-services:4.3.15:.
  Required by:
  project :

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is telling you, that you try to use group `com.google.gms.google-services` name `4.3.15` version  .

Fix your dependency to be the proper `com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15` instead of `com.google.gms.google-services:4.3.15` and it will work.

Comment: please see [ask]'s recommendations on avoiding answering poorly asked questions.

Answer (score 0):

classpath 'com.google.gms.google-services:4.3.15'

Please check your previous line format & paste the dependency in the same form.
I solved this problem in this way.